# Same Node, different child Selenium Xpath Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

This is the example

```html
<div>
<div _ngcontent-c20="" class="element">
<span _ngcontent-c20="" class="chip-name tv-h-no-select"> element1 </span><!---->
<i _ngcontent-c20="" aria-hidden="true" class="close"><!---->close<!----></i></div>
<div _ngcontent-c20="" class="element">
<span _ngcontent-c20="" class="chip-name tv-h-no-select"> element2 </span><!---->
<i _ngcontent-c20="" aria-hidden="true" class="close"><!---->close<!----></i></div>
<div _ngcontent-c20="" class="element">
<span _ngcontent-c20="" class="chip-name tv-h-no-select"> element3 </span><!---->
<i _ngcontent-c20="" aria-hidden="true" class="close"><!---->close<!----></i></div>
<div _ngcontent-c20="" class="element">
<span _ngcontent-c20="" class="chip-name tv-h-no-select"> element4 </span><!---->
<i _ngcontent-c20="" aria-hidden="true" class="close"><!---->close<!----></i></div>
</div>
```

Here is the thing,

I want to create an xpath that press the "CLOSE" button but depending on which element I want to close...

we have 4 elements, but I just want to press the close button for the element that I want

I would like to create an xpath with Axes in order to pick the element that I want:

this is my current xpath:

```
//div//span[contains(text(), 'element1')]
```

but with this xpath is just clicking the element1 and not the "close" button.

now I would like to create an xpath choosing the element with Axes and identifying the "close" button to be pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath.

```
//span[normalize-space(.)='element2']/parent::div/i[normalize-space(.)='close']
```

Just change the element that you want.

Comment: lol, that works... thank you so much! I'd like to understand why are you using *normalize-space(.)* or what does mean? :)

Comment: just to make sure to ignore any spaces before and after the text. Just a simple trim.